# GeoCode Timedout. Is error caused by dataframe table?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, geocode

this is my data
d=pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Lagos_State_local_government_areas_by_population')

dfr=d[2]

dfr['Locale']=dfr.LGA + ', Lagos, Nigeria'

I intend to use this code

```
from geopy.exc import GeocoderTimedOut 

for address in (dfr['Locale']):
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="lagos_explorer")
    location = geolocator.geocode(address, timeout=20000)    
    if location:
        latitude = location.latitude
        longitude = location.longitude
    else:
        latitude= "Not Available"
        longitude= "Not Available"

    dfr['Latitude']=pd.Series([latitude])
    dfr['Longitude']=pd.Series([longitude])
```

dfr

To loop through the table, then assign the respective coordinates. The problem is, it timedout after inserting the first row, and then populates NaN for others.

I'm new to coding, please help.

Comment: could you provide with minimum data to test?

Answer (score 0):

Created a counter for the index instead.

```
from geopy.exc import GeocoderTimedOut
for i in (dfr.index):
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="lag_explore")
    location = geolocator.geocode(dfr['Locale'][i], timeout=20000)

    if location:
        latitude = location.latitude
        longitude = location.longitude
    else:
        latitude= None
        longitude= None

    dfr['Latitude'][i]=latitude
    dfr['Longitude'][i]=longitude


dfr
```